# value from JS file to JSON but the value appears to be null

Tags: javascript, .net, json

dears,

I'm currently trying to send a value from JS file to JSON but the value chosenTxt appears to be null.

```
$('.Dropdown1 .Dropdown2').change(function () {



        $.postJSON('/files/html.aspx', {
            action: 'myAction', id: $(this).val(), chosenTxt: $('.Dropdown1 .Dropdown2 option:selected').text()
        }, function (j) {

            $('.html .content').html(j.html);

        });

    });
```

even I tried alert before sending the values and appeared there exist a value, but in my json when i call it it is just `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to join the text of two dropdowns, I don't think that `.text` can work like that, try this:

```
chosenTxt: $('.Dropdown1 option:selected').text() + ' ' + $('.Dropdown2 option:selected').text()
```

Comment: But the value i wanted got printed when i printed it in alert